# What are some good reference on Stochastic Differential Equations and Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

There are quite a few books that use functional-analytical tools to study ODE/PDE. However, I haven't seen such a book on SDE. Some books seem to allude to this, but I cannot find a good enough reference.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: da Prato: infinite dimensional analysis; da Prato, Zabczyk: Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions

Comment: @da Prato. I am already in love with the second book. Can you post it as an answer? I will accept it. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two good starting points might be da Prato: infinite dimensional analysis and da Prato, Zabczyk: Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions.